# What are the formal English words for "compensated public holiday"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

As per the title, what are the formal English words for "compensated public holiday"? As in when a public holiday falls on a Sunday, normally the next day (Monday) will be a day off. How should I refer to that "day off"?

I would like to put the word in a sentence similar to this: I will be going back to my hometown this weekend because Monday is a [compensated public holiday]. The words inside [...] should be replaced with another formal English words (if there is any).

Note: it can be a single word or a phrase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is generally referred to as a : ***[compensatory holiday](https://glosbe.com/en/en/compensatory%20holiday)***:

> - If a holiday falls on an employee's regularly scheduled day off, the employee will receive holiday credit, sometimes referred to as Holiday Compensatory Time.

Comment: Will it be weird if I put it inside the sentence i mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 1):

It's called a **[substitute day](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays)**, in the UK.

> If a bank holiday is on a weekend, a ‘substitute’ weekday becomes a
>   bank holiday, normally the following Monday.

Comment: [This reference](http://bank-holidays.info/what-is-substitute-day/) is perhaps more convincing evidence that 'substitute day' is acquiring compound-noun status.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, if it's a statutory swap of the public holiday onto another day (e.g. the example you quote - for example, when Christmas Day falls on a weekend) then they're referred to as *substitute days*:

- https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays

If it's an elective switch (e.g. when the employee works the public holiday but then has to have a different day off instead) then they're referred to as *lieu days* (or *time off in lieu* / *TOIL*):

- http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/lieu-days.html
- http://thelawdictionary.org/lieu-days/
- http://www.workingrights.co.uk/time-off-lieu-working-additional-hours.html

(those include non-UK links, so I think the term is pretty universal in the English-speaking world)

Comment: but lieu days are more like "compensation for working overtime". It doesn't mean "compensating for a public holiday falling on a Sunday" which is more related to what I am searching for

Comment: Yes, I put that in for completeness - you'd need to go to *substitute day* (in the UK, anyway) for that scenario. Other countries may vary, as I know not all countries give you a substitute if the PH falls on a weekend.

Comment: 'Bank holiday in lieu' is  also used. ([Calendarpedia](http://www.calendarpedia.co.uk/bank-holidays/bank-holidays-2017.html))